# UIView memory release

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

When do I have to release `UIView` in the below code?

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10,
120.0, 100)]; 

return headerView;
```

Thanks for any help

[image]

Comment: Always research before posting a question (StackOverflow informs you about that when you post a question). This question has been asked several times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you're going to use the view. If you assign the view returned from the method to some object (for example to a UIViewController) and that object retains it then you should autorelese the view in the above function. This way you'll make sure that it gets released automatically after the method loop ends and also it'll be alive long enough for an object to retain it. So the code will be like this:

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10,
120.0, 100)]; 
[headerView autorelese];
return headerView;
```

For ex:

```
myViewController.view=theMethodThatReturnsView;//which is the above method
```

Comment: Yeah,in the above image, the analyzer warns you that you do not autorelease it. If you do not autorelease it before you return it, then you will never have a chance to release it unless you unload the viewcontroller's view.However this will not cause any errors unless you're out of memory.Just add the autorelese line and I'm absolutely sure the warning will be gone.

Comment: ya i did so return [headerView autorelease]; and the warning is gone now..thank you dude

Comment: The way you chose to do is better than mine

Answer (score 3):

return it as auto-release. The one who uses this functions will take care of its ownership. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770437/if-a-function-creates-and-returns-an-object-should-it-be-in-the-autorelease-poo).